# Find a function $M$ such that $M(x)=1 \forall x\neq 0$ and $M(0)=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Find a function $F$ from $S*S$ to $\{0,1\}$ where $S$ is the set of first $12$ positive integers such that :

$$F(a,b) = \begin{cases}0 &, \text{for $b \ge a$}\\ 1 & \text{otherwise }. \end{cases}$$

My Attempt:

$$F(a,b)=\left\lfloor\frac{a+12}{b+12}\right\rfloor G(a,b)$$

Let $G(a,b)=M(a-b)$, 
Now we have to find a function $M$ from $S \cup P\cup  {0}$($P$ is the set of first twelve negaive integers) to $(1,0)$ such that $M(0)=0$ and $M(x) =1 \forall x>1$

Since the limit does not exist at $0$ ,therefore I can't use trig or exponential function s etc.

Any help in direction would be appreciated.

PS: keep it as simple as possible. I am willing to use  $\mod,floor$ and $abs$ to construct $M$

Comment: The simplest function is the $F$ that you defined up there, the one with the curly bracket. Without any other assumption on $F$, it is really hard to understand what you would like to achieve here. Same from $M$, a block-defined function is the easiest one.

Comment: I would say  M(x) = |sign(x)|

Comment: @georg That can't be as $\;|sign(x)|=0\iff sign(x)=0\iff x=0\;$

Comment: @Timbuc - maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply $$F(a,b)=\left\lfloor\frac{a+12}{b+13}\right\rfloor$$
It works as you defined it without the function $M$,anyway is your co-domain $\{0,1\}$ instead of $(0,1)$ since $0\not\in(0,1)$ and $1\not\in(0,1)$